# Has anyone ever seen a presentation/article comparing native mobile navigation/UI elements?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns

I'm looking for a presentation or article where someone goes through all the native UI and navigation elements for different mobile platforms* correlating them to each other and explaining when to use each. The need seems so obvious to me that I think surely it must have been done and I don't need to do it myself. However, I cannot find it anywhere.

> * mobile platforms - I would like to see iOS6, iOS7, Android, Windows Mobile, [maybe] Blackberry
>
> yes I think iOS6 & iOS7 are different enough to warrant seeing them compared separately.

Comment: I get the value in comparing between iOS and Android, but since Apple stipulated all new apps must be optimized to iOS7, is there still a value in comparing it to iOS6. Especially since it's predominantly a UI refresh rather than change in functionality?

Comment: @micap, I guess having iOS6 in there isn't really that important, but I do think that it valuable for the research. It tells a lot about the evolution of mobile UX.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some stuff:
1) http://www.istartedsomething.com/20131109/flat-vs-flat-a-comparison-of-windows-phone-and-ios-7-app-designs/
2) http://jackg.org/beyond-flat

Comment: These are both great! Thank you. You get an up vote from me. What I'd really like to find is something that I can take to meetings and pull out when people are suggesting we do terrible inconsistent things.

Comment: inconsistent between the different OS's or inconsistent within one platform?

Comment: Richard, I think you'd better take devices with different OSes and look at standard apps on them, like: settings, calendar, notes, calculator, messages, contacts, etc. - all this apps solves the same tasks.

Comment: @Humanoit, that is a great suggestion. I'm going to look at those apps this weekend. I'd really like to see that comparison made. I hope I don't have to be the one to do it.

Comment: @micap, my goal is to learn and teach others how to be consistent with the accepted usage paradigms for each OS.